# Fivestar stopped working

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

My fivestar rating has stopped working.  I'm using views to display both average user rating and user rating.

Strange thing is my old views which have ratings do work and user rating areinteractive. I've created new views and the user rating isn't interactive.

This happened a while ago when I updated core to 6.16 and some other modules.  I am now on 6.17.

Has anybody had this issue?

Comment: I assume you cleared the cache

Comment: You're going to have to give us some more information - Are you using the node display on the old views and the field display on the new ones?  There's not really enough information to go on.

Comment: Use the Logs, Luke! (in other words: have you checked the watchdog, PHP error logs and MySQL error logs? And can you paste any interesting bits into your question?)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you backed up your site before updating. Did you try rolling back the code updates? How about if you roll back BOTH code updates AND data, then start upgrading one module at at time, then checking on each update when the Views stop working? If newer code is the problem, that should fix it.